# Show/Hide ngx-boostrap alert

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I'd like to show the ngx-bootstrap alert multiple times with the `[dismissOnTimeout]` attribute; however, after it's dismissed the first time I can't figure out how to show it again.

My Angular html template:

```html
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>

<div *ngIf="showMessage">
    <alert type="success" [dismissOnTimeout]="dismissValue">
        <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully upload (disappearing in 3,2,1..).
    </alert>
  </div>
```

and in my compoent's method:

```js
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.showMessage = true;
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
```

So once I call `openModal()`, the `alert<>` opens and gets dismissed the first time.
I'm trying to figure out how to reset the alert, so I can display that alert again - i.e.simulating a toaster type of component.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way to show the alert that has been hidden after a timeout but you can get this working with a little workaround ( `ngIf` and alert's `onClosed` output).

```
<alert *ngIf="isOpen" type="success" dismissOnTimeout="5000" (onClosed)="isOpen = false">
  5 sec timeout
</alert>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="isOpen = true">Show again</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfxjgi?file=app%2Fdismiss-on-timeout.html

Comment: That's perfect. I figured I would need to hook into the api, but wasn't sure exactly how. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be via using the document and finding the alert you want to close and adding an id:

```
<alert id="alertid" *ngIf="isOpen" type="success" (onClosed)="isOpen = false">
  5 sec timeout
</alert>
```

And then in the part you wish to programmatically close the control.

```
const element = this._document.getElementById('alertid').getElementsByTagName('button');

if (element && element.length) {
   element[0].click();
}
```

where document is defined as:

```
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) {}
```

In this way you can close the alert at any time/place you want and can dispense with the timeout.